# Kendo UI + Spring MVC integration

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, kendo-ui

Where can I find a working example of **Kendo UI** (Web) integrated with **Spring MVC**?
I've started developing an application that has a complicated business logic (managed by Spring and accessible as a restful services).

I've seen only some examples which integrate kendo and ASP.NET but none with Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo UI for JSP comes with a working Spring MVC application. You can download the public beta today.